# Nested for loop for iteration

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
matrix = np.zeros((106, 106))

for k in result:
    p = result[0]
    for j in result:
        q = result[1]
        matrix[result.index(k), result.index(j)] = frdist(p, q)
print(matrix)
```

I wrote some code, now I want to iterate this code, apply for the dataset. But I am getting same result.

Why I am getting same result?

```
[[0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994 ... 0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994]
 [0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994 ... 0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994]
 [0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994 ... 0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994]
 ...
 [0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994 ... 0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994]
 [0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994 ... 0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994]
 [0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994 ... 0.13215994 0.13215994 0.13215994]]
```

## UPDATED:

RecursionError happens in this part. Can not be changed because it is basic part of [algorithm](https://pypi.org/project/frechetdist/). Any ideas?

```
__all__ = ['frdist']


def _c(ca, i, j, p, q):

    if ca[i, j] > -1:
        return ca[i, j]
    elif i == 0 and j == 0:
        ca[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(p[i]-q[j])
    elif i > 0 and j == 0:
        ca[i, j] = max(_c(ca, i-1, 0, p, q), np.linalg.norm(p[i]-q[j]))
    elif i == 0 and j > 0:
        ca[i, j] = max(_c(ca, 0, j-1, p, q), np.linalg.norm(p[i]-q[j]))
    elif i > 0 and j > 0:
        ca[i, j] = max(
            min(
                _c(ca, i-1, j, p, q),
                _c(ca, i-1, j-1, p, q),
                _c(ca, i, j-1, p, q)
            ),
            np.linalg.norm(p[i]-q[j])
            )
    else:
        ca[i, j] = float('inf')

    return ca[i, j]
```

Comment: You're looping over result, but `p` and `q` get set to the same value on each iteration (result[0] and result[1] respectively), so you calculate the same thing every time. I think you mean `for p in result: for q in result:`

Comment: I guess you meant `frdist(i, j)`

Comment: @ALollz Now my matrix is 0 except second number of the row which is 0.13215994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for k, p in enumerate(result):
    for j, q in enumerate(result):
        matrix[k, j] = frdist(p, q)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for small data. So I accepted the answer. But in my case I got the `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: @Mamed how big are you thinking? I mean this grows quadratically so at some point this becomes problematic in terms of time. But still are you sure there isn't something recursive in `frdist(p,q)` that is causing the error (perhaps some check that never happens)? A simple toy example making a 10K x 10K matrix works for me